# Efficiently find row intersections of two 2-D numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to figure out an efficient way of finding row intersections of two `np.arrays`.

Two arrays have the same shapes, and duplicate values in each row cannot happen.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[2,5,6],
              [8,2,3],
              [4,1,5],
              [1,7,9]])

b = np.array([[2,3,4],  # one element(2) in common with a[0] -> 1
              [7,4,3],  # one element(3) in common with a[1] -> 1
              [5,4,1],  # three elements(5,4,1) in common with a[2] -> 3
              [7,6,9]]) # two element(9,7) in common with a[3] -> 2
```

My desired output is : `np.array([1,1,3,2])`

It is easy to do this with a loop:

```
def get_intersect1ds(a, b):
    result = np.empty(a.shape[0], dtype=np.int)
    for i in xrange(a.shape[0]):
        result[i] = (len(np.intersect1d(a[i], b[i])))
    return result
```

Result:

```
>>> get_intersect1ds(a, b)
array([1, 1, 3, 2])
```

But is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Hmm. Can `a` and `b` have duplicated values in each row?

Comment: @MrE good point, duplicates cannot happen. Thanks.

Comment: How large do you expect the input arrays to be?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, 4,000,000 by 25 and I probably would have do this operation a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have no duplicates within a row you can try to replicate what `np.intersect1d` does under the hood (see the source code [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.7.0/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L199)):

```
>>> c = np.hstack((a, b))
>>> c
array([[2, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4],
       [8, 2, 3, 7, 4, 3],
       [4, 1, 5, 5, 4, 1],
       [1, 7, 9, 7, 6, 9]])
>>> c.sort(axis=1)
>>> c
array([[2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [2, 3, 3, 4, 7, 8],
       [1, 1, 4, 4, 5, 5],
       [1, 6, 7, 7, 9, 9]])
>>> c[:, 1:] == c[:, :-1]
array([[ True, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>> np.sum(c[:, 1:] == c[:, :-1], axis=1)
array([1, 1, 3, 2])
```

Comment: Can you explain the algorithm behind the line c[:, 1:] == c[:, :-1]?

Answer (score 2):

This answer might not be viable, because if the input has shape (N, M), it generates an intermediate array with size (N, M, M), but it's always fun to see what you can do with broadcasting:

```
In [43]: a
Out[43]: 
array([[2, 5, 6],
       [8, 2, 3],
       [4, 1, 5],
       [1, 7, 9]])

In [44]: b
Out[44]: 
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [7, 4, 3],
       [5, 4, 1],
       [7, 6, 9]])

In [45]: (np.expand_dims(a, -1) == np.expand_dims(b, 1)).sum(axis=-1).sum(axis=-1)
Out[45]: array([1, 1, 3, 2])
```

For large arrays, the method could be made more memory-friendly by doing the operation in batches.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a clean pure-numpy solution, but the following suggestion should speed things up, potentially dramatically:

1. use [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/). It is as simple as decorating your `get_intersect1ds` function with `@autojit`
2. pass `assume_unique = True` when you call [`intersect1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html#numpy.intersect1d)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to numba, but I was thinking cython. I think it should work as well. Thanks for the suggestion.