# Conditionally add 1 to int element of a NumPy record array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, addition, record

I have a large NumpPy record array 250 million rows by 9 columns (MyLargeRec). and I need to add 1 to the 7th column (dtype = "int") if the the index of that row is in another list or 300,000 integers(MyList). If this was a normal python list I would use the following simple code...

```
for m in MyList:
    MyLargeRec[m][6]+=1
```

However I can not seem to get a similar functionality using the NumPy record array. I have tried a few options such as nditer, but this will not let me select the specific indices I want.

Now you may say that this is not what NumPy was designed for, so let me explain why I a using this format. I am using it is because it only takes 30 mins to build the record array from scratch whereas it takes over 24 hours if using a conventional 2D list format. I spent all of yesterday trying to find a way to do this and could not, I eventually converted it to a list using...

```
MyLargeList = list(MyLargeRec)
```

so I could use the simple code above to achieve what I want, however this took 8.5 hours to perform this function.

Therefore, can anyone tell me first, is there a method to achieve what i want within a NumPy record array? and second, if not, any ideas on the best methods within python 2.7 to create, update and store such a large 2D matrix?

Many thanks

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code...

```
for m in MyList:
    MyLargeRec[m][6]+=1
```

does actually work, silly question by me.

Comment: What's the shape and dtype of MyLargeRec?

Answer (score 1):

```
your_array[index_list, 6] += 1
```

Numpy allows you to construct some pretty neat slices. This selects the 6th column of all rows in your list of indices and adds 1 to each. (Note that if an index appears multiple times in your list of indices, this will still only add 1 to the corresponding cell.)

Comment: That looks very neat indeed, However it kept giving me an error "too many indices for array". Also multiple indices do exist and these need to be counted too. However modifying it to my original format of a for loop above seems to have worked. I can not figure why this wasn't working before. Thanks for helping though, it put me on the right track.

Comment: It would help if you provide example input as runnable Python code. Specifically, create `MyLargeRec` and `MyList` with the appropriate number of dimansions. Otherwise there is a lot of guesswork involved in answering your question and it leads to a lot of wasted time. Here is an example of a question that provides example input: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19731022/553404