# Same code, same inputs but different output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have been trying to figure out what is going on here for quite some time but can't figure it out.

Basically the inputs will be two numpy arrays which have 3 columns representing 
x, y, z coordinates and a different number of rows.
Thus like this: [[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2],...,[xn,yn,zn]]

The output will be an array containing the intersecting rows.

For this problem I found a solution here: 
[Efficiently find row intersections of two 2-D numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731022/efficiently-find-row-intersections-of-two-2-d-numpy-arrays)

I tried this function in separate module and it does perfectly what I want I to do, so I tried implementing it in my existing python code and this is were it goes wrong.

I have the following class which holds the function in question:

```
class HssGeometries(ABC):
    '''
    Abstract class for hot spot stress approach compatible geometries.
    '''

    def __init__(self, coords_weld, coords_surf):
        self.coords_weld = coords_weld
        self.coords_surf = coords_surf
        np.savetxt(r"..\coords_surf.csv", self.coords_surf, delimiter=",")
        np.savetxt(r"..\coords_weld.csv", self.coords_weld, delimiter=",")
        self.intersect = self.matrix_intersection(coords_weld, coords_surf)

    @staticmethod
    def matrix_intersection(A, B):
        '''
        Return points  (node coords) that are in both matrices
        A and B are multidimensional ndarrays of coordinates
        (i.e.[[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2], ..., [xn,yn,zn]])
        '''
        nrows, ncols = A.shape
        dtype={'names':['f{}'.format(i) for i in range(ncols)],
            'formats':ncols * [A.dtype]}
        C = np.intersect1d(A.view(dtype), B.view(dtype))
        return C.view(A.dtype).reshape(-1, ncols)
```

Then I have a class which inherits from the HSSGeometries class.

```
    class TubularJoint(HssGeometries):

        def __init__(self, coords_weld, coords_surf):
            super().__init__(coords_weld, coords_surf)
```

The problem occurs when I instantiate an object of the class TubularJoint. For example: when I use two input arrays which have shapes (180,3) and (2520,3), the result is an array with a shape of (37,3) which I know is incorrect. I thought it might be due to some error earlier in my code (not included) resulting in the wrong input arrays, but when I save the two input arrays (coords_weld and coords_surf) to a csv file (you can download them [here](http://www.filedropper.com/csvarrays)) and then run the code below separately, (which contains exactly the same function as the the one above) the output is a <s>(60,1)</s> (60,3) array which is the correct one.

```
def matrix_intersection(A, B):
    '''
    Return points  (node coords) that are in both matrices
    A and B are multidimensional ndarrays of coordinates
    (i.e.[[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2], ..., [xn,yn,zn]])
    '''

    nrows, ncols = A.shape
    dtype={'names':['f{}'.format(i) for i in range(ncols)],
        'formats':ncols * [A.dtype]}
    C = np.intersect1d(A.view(dtype), B.view(dtype))
    return C.view(A.dtype).reshape(-1, ncols)

coords_surf = np.genfromtxt('coords_surf.csv', delimiter=',')
coords_weld = np.genfromtxt('coords_weld.csv', delimiter=',')

print(coords_weld.shape)
print(coords_surf.shape)
print(matrix_intersection(coords_weld, coords_surf).shape)
```

Any idea what might be causing this different return value?

Comment: If I had to guess, my first suspicion would be that, somewhere in your code, you're making a shallow copy of something that later gets modified and where a deep copy should have been made.

Comment: I ran your code with the class and without the class and they both give a shape of `(60, 3)`. So, the issue is not in the code you added here. And the shapes you mention are both incorrect.

Comment: The shape (60, 3) is actually correct, I've made a typo in my original question. I think I have figured out the problem. For me it also works in both cases with the provided csv files, yet it didn't in the actual run code. Is it possible that it is caused because the arrays that I am comparing in my run code contain floats? Whilst when running the case separately they both come from csv files which makes the data the same?